# Unable to understand this error while running cmake

Tags: linux, qt, cmakelists-options

I am getting this error while building my package (cmake ..)

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:297 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0042 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Building Debug
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: date_time thread serialization filesystem system program_options unit_test_framework chrono 
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:275 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:338 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.7", minimum required is "4.4.3") 
-- Found OMPL: /opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libompl.so  
-- Found Armadillo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so (found version "9.800.4") 
-- Found TinyXML: /usr/include  
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OMPLAPPBASE_LIBRARY
    linked by target "bsp-app-demo" in directory /home/nishant/edpl-ompl
OMPLAPP_LIBRARY
    linked by target "bsp-app-demo" in directory /home/nishant/edpl-ompl
    linked by target "bsp_lib" in directory /home/nishant/edpl-ompl

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nishant/edpl-ompl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/nishant/edpl-ompl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried many ways to get the not found problem solved, however it does not get solved. Other than that I think there might be a problem with OMPL that I am not able to understand

Comment: What are `OMPLAPPBASE_LIBRARY` and `OMPLAPP_LIBRARY` variables?

Comment: At a guess the project is dead and not compatible w/ current toolsets?  No commits in 7 years .. https://github.com/sauravag/edpl-ompl ... maybe raise an issue on their github page ...